# MySQL Java connector fails to initialize when JVM 8 used

Tags: java, mysql

I use Java 8 EA on Raspberry Pi under Arch. I limited to Java 8 because Arch is hard float point support. When I connect to MySql database I am getting the following exception:

> message:    java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData, method: supportsRefCursors signature: ()Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
>   error code: 0
>   java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData, method: supportsRefCursors signature: ()Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

I did research on net and common recommendation is downgrade JDK which I can't do. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Java Lambda version . Java lambda version  solved this problem.

http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/